# How to get fetch data from firestore as a map in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a newbie trying to make a blog view for my application and for that I want to fetch all the links saved as string in cloud firestore.  It would be nice if I could get the values as string or if I could get a complete map and then reference the value to get data.
How do I do that?

Here's an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDo4d.png

As you can see I want to fetch the https links as string in my flutter project.
And I should be able to add more https links in the future in my cloud firestore, and the application should update itself. How do I do that?

Comment: This is a general question and I would recommend reading the Firestore documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.